# How to draw topological defect line in LaTeX?

Tags: notation, software

This is somewhat between TeX stackexchange and physics stackexchange. With Latex, it became much more easier to write equations, and with tikz, pictures can be drawn.

However, with the introduction of the generalized symmetry, the equations of the topological defect lines were often equations of diagrams, instead of equations of alphabetic symbols. For example, in "Topological Defect Lines and Renormalization Group Flows in Two Dimensions" [arXiv:1802.04445](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04445), the TeX Source indicated that most of the equations were written by graphs and pictures. It has became ridiculously slow to take notes.

How to draw topological defect line in latex? or if it was recommended to write these equations in latex at all?

Comment: Would [tex.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought about that but it's too specialized, and it's not like the solution didn't exists, it's just ridiculously slow and long. Currently I made sever "base graphs", and the simple equation in latex is often near a hundred lines of code.